# iPhone app (Phonegap) not scrolling on iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, cordova, scroll

I have made a simple app using jquery mobile and Phonegap. It works fine on the iPhone 4, 4s, 5, 5s under iOS6, 7 and 8 but on an iPhone 6 I can not swipe to the bottom of the page when the content is longer than the screen...

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: same issue i had. use "overflow : scroll"  on the main div.
Not sure whats the issue

Comment: try this css:   .ui-page.ui-body-c.ui-page-header-fixed.ui-page-footer-fixed.ui-page-active{height:auto;}